# Rebuild SessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I want to dynamically update the session Factory object.As i want to dynamically update/change the database credential and without restarting server i want these changes to reflected in data source and session Factory is recreated.

```
public class DataSourceConfiguration  
{
    private String url;
    private int port;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String schema;

        @Bean(name="dataSource")    
        public DataSource getDataSource()
        {           
            DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();        
            ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String urlPath= "jdbc:mysql://"+url+":"+port+"/"+schema+"?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
            ds.setUrl(urlPath);
            ds.setUsername(userName);
            ds.setPassword(password);           
            return ds;
        }

        @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
        @Scope("prototype")
        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws Exception 
        {
            Properties properties  = getHibernateProperties();
            LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.netlink.notification.modal" });
            factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
            factory.setHibernateProperties(properties);
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() 
        {
                try 
                {
                    return new HibernateTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
        }


         @Bean
         public Properties getHibernateProperties()
         {
             Properties properties = new Properties();
             properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
             properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);             
             return properties;
         }

}
```

Comment: Also interested in knowing how to properly reset/rebuild SessionFactory in a Spring web app.